# Prevent email to root@domain

Tags: exim

I'm running Ubuntu Server 12.04 as a web server and use Exim4 for sending confirmation emails and such. Is there a way to set a system-wide email address for the root user? In other words, I'd like ALL email to go to a different address rather than root@domain.com. For example, this command...

```
echo "test" | mail -v -s test root
```

...would go to a different address, as well as all cron tasks that root executes:

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can edit /etc/aliases and look for the line starting with:
root:

or add one. It might be commented out.
Then follow the instructions for your MTA to reload the configuation. For Exim 4 you don't have to restart it actually, but when running Postfix (Ubuntu's default MTA) you'll need to run `newaliases`.

or update it in /root/.forward

Comment: I don't have sendmail installed. Would I need to restart anything if I just edit /root/.forward?

Comment: nope, you would not need to restart anything.

Answer (score 4):

In the root account home folder add a ".forward" file that contains the e-mail address or alternate account name on that system for where you want e-mail to be redirected to.

So, make a file named ".forward" containing one line that reads either:

name@domain

or simply:

name

I hope that is clear enough. All e-mail coming into root should automatically be forward to to the other mailbox.

Comment: From searching, the .foward appears to be part of sendmail. Is there a different configuration needed for exim?

Comment: This doesn't work on my system. Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Hmm... strange. You mentioned you don't have sendmail installed. I'm curious why not? That's probably the problem.

Comment: It's close to stock install of Ubuntu. Any reason I need sendmail in addition to exim? I thought they were accomplishing the same task.

Comment: Hmm... sorry. That I don't know. I always run sendmail on my servers. Maybe someone else can chime in on that question.